# Create welcome script displaying last executed commands

Tags: shell-script, centos

I am trying to create a script display some **user information and the last 5 executed commands** like what in this image:

[image]

, after some research, I did the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello $USER, Your UID is $UID , Your full name is $user_full_name "
export HISTIMEFORMAT= `%F %T %t`
history 5
```

Sadly the output was like this:

```
Hi user1 , Your UID is 500 , Your full name is: 
bash: fg: no job contorl
```

any help please?

Comment: Do you actually have a space ofter that `=`? Also, if this is something that should be displayed when an interactive shell starts, then why not do it as part of running `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: This will only work if `$USER`'s `.bashrc` doesn't change the value of `$HISTFILE`. Many users do.

Comment: I added it to ```/etc/profile.d/``` @Kusalananda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your "**export HISTTIMEFORMAT**" line to be

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T %t"
```

- no space after equal symbol =
- use double quote symbols " instead of back quote symbols `

**Edited to answer regarding user_full_name.**

There us no **user_full_name** variable by default, but we can create it.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# taking first part (up to a first comma symbol)
# from "Full name of the user (GECOS)" field of /etc/passwd file
# and removing double quote symbols from it
user_full_name=$(/bin/getent passwd $USER |cut -d: -f5|cut -d, -f1|sed 's/"//g')
# if that field is empty, using username as full name
[ -z "$user_full_name" ] && user_full_name=$USER
export user_full_name
#
echo "Hello $USER, Your UID is $UID , Your full name is $user_full_name "
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T %t"
history 5
```

Comment: It is better to edit your answer to include these explanations rather than commenting your own answer.

Comment: what about ```$user_full_name``` is that right?

Comment: @AragonS That's a variable that you must have declared yourself. There is to my knowledge no default variable that holds the user's full name.

Comment: Your answer misses the fact that ```history``` command does not work in a non-interactive shell so you need to execute it first and get the output to another file which add the content to this script, I am accepting the answer and hope you edit it, Thanks for the help